# Replay Risks Post the TheDAO HF

Tags: ether, the-dao, ethereum-classic, replay-attack

Is ETH (or ETC, for that matter) that was purchased *after* the HF in their respective chains at any risk of replay attack such that splitting via contracts is still advisable, or is that just a risk for any ETH held pre-HF?

How will replay apply to the ETC produced from DAO-C withdrawals on Aug 30, or will it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the replay attack is when an account on the ETH chain sends an TX but that TX is still valid on the ETC chain so it gets execute there also.

It depends where you got the ETH or ETC. If you got it from a big exchange they have likly already split it.

The refund contract on ETC for DAOc does not have a matching account on ETH so it will not be replayed. But if you have send it to an account on ETC that has ETH also then a TX sent from that address may be replayed. So you need to keep both chains separate. Until someone steps up and hard forks to prevent the replay attack.